# Code in online compiler shows segmentation fault program finished with exit code 139

Tags: c

I am trying to write code in online compiler but it shows segmentation fault program finished with exit code 139

*this is the code i have been working on*

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
    int arrayLength ,array[20] ,sum , array_sum=0 ,j;
    printf("enter the no of elements in your array");
    scanf("%d" , &arrayLength);
    printf("enter your array");
    for (int i=0 ; i<arrayLength; i++){
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("your array is");
    for (int i=0; i < arrayLength; i++){
        printf("%d",array[i]);
    }
    printf("enter the sum");
    scanf("%d" ,&sum);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if(array_sum<sum){
            array_sum=array_sum+array[i];
            continue;
        }
        else if(array_sum>sum && i<arrayLength){
            array_sum = array_sum - array[j];
            continue;
            
        }
        else if ( array_sum=sum){
            printf("your sum can be found between array elements %d and %d ", j ,i);
            continue;
        }
        else{
            printf("not in this array");
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Even without a debugger, this is helpful https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What's your input/output and desired results? Also, what's the logic of your code (i.e. what does it do)?

Comment: The variable `j` is never initialized or set to any value, so at the point of `array[j]`, `j` is likely some garbage value such as -1037927, or whatever it might be, and this will cause a segfault.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to address `array[j]` without initializing `j`, and you have to be careful not to input an array size bigger than `20`.